# Parent flexbox to grow/shrink based on another flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent div with flexbox in it. There is a flexbox to the right of the parent div.

The right flexbox can have 1, 2 or 3 items that will make it grow/shrink.

I would like the parent div to shrink/grow based on the items in the flexbox to the right.

I thought the parent div will do it automatically but it does not happen that way.

Please advise what is going wrong.`

Here's my codepen [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XVydeo).

```css
.overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
  left: 65px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 255px;
  z-index: 4;
  background-color: cyan
}

.overlay-range {
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  right: -8em;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

span {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-range">
    <input type="range">
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <span> + </span>
    <span> - </span>
    <span> * </span>
    <span> % </span>
    <span> / </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify the output that you are expecting. Put it in a picture form for better understanding.

Comment: @Michael_B : Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that your `inner` is using absolute positioning.

An absolute positioned element is taken out of flow and as such will not affect its parent.

If you e.g. make the `overlay` a flex container, remove `position: absolute` on the `inner`, you can use auto margin on the `inner`, and right align it.

Stack snippet

```css
.overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    height: 48px;
    left: 65px; 
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 255px;
    z-index: 4;
    background-color: cyan
}

.overlay-range{
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
    display: flex;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
    bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    align-self: flex-start;
   }

span {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-range">
    <input type="range"></div>
   <div class="inner">
     <span> + </span>
     <span> - </span>
     <span> * </span>
     <span> % </span>
     <span> / </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

For the `overlay` to also adjust its width, remove the `right: 255px` on the `overlay`.

When done like this, you can also remove the newly added `margin-left: auto`, since it won't have any effect anymore.

Stack snippet

```css
.overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    height: 48px;
    left: 65px; 
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    background-color: cyan
}

.overlay-range{
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
    display: flex;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
    bottom: 20px;
    align-self: flex-start;
   }

span {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-range">
    <input type="range"></div>
   <div class="inner">
     <span> + </span>
     <span> - </span>
     <span> * </span>
     <span> % </span>
     <span> / </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

Technically, you could keep `display: block` on `overlay`, and change the `display: flex` to `display: inline-flex` (so they line up side-by-side), though I find the previous version better.

```css
.overlay {
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
  left: 65px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  background-color: cyan
}

.overlay-range {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  bottom: 20px;
}

span {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="overlay-range">
    <input type="range">
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <span> + </span>
    <span> - </span>
    <span> * </span>
    <span> % </span>
    <span> / </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I could tweak it accordingly and got what I wanted. Your explanation was awesome. Appreciate it.